# how to define a constant array and check if a value is in the array for Pig Latin

Tags: apache-pig

I want to define an array of user Ids in Pig and then filter data if the userId from the input is NOT in that array,
How do I do this in pig latin? Below is the example of what I intend to do

Thanks

```
inputData = load '$INPUT' USING PigStorage('|') AS (useriD:chararray,controllerAction:chararray,url:chararray,browserName:chararray,IsMobile:chararray,exceptionDetails:chararray,renderTime:int,serviceHostId:int,auditEventTime:chararray);
filteredInput = filter inputData by controllerAction is not null and auditEventTime is not null and serviceHostId is not null and renderTime is not null and useriD in ('2be2df06-f4ba-4d87-8938-09d867d3f2fe','ac1ac6bf-d151-49fc-8c7c-2b52d2efbb58','f00aec16-36e5-46ae-b7cb-a0f1eeefe609','258890f9-102a-4f8e-a001-ae24d2e25269','cf221779-a077-472c-b377-cca4a9230e1b');
```

Thanks Murali..I tried the approach of declaring a variable and then using Flatten and stringSplit to join..However I get the following error
 Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'flatteneduserids'

```
%declare REQUIRED_USER_IDS 'xxxxx,yyyyy,sssss' ;

inputData = load '$INPUT' USING PigStorage('|') AS (useriD:chararray,controllerAction:chararray,url:chararray,browserName:chararray,IsMobile:chararray,exceptionDetails:chararray,renderTime:int,serviceHostId:int,auditEventTime:chararray);

filteredInput = filter inputData by controllerAction is not null and auditEventTime is not null and serviceHostId is not null and renderTime is not null;

flatteneduserids = FLATTEN(STRSPLIT('$REQUIRED_USER_IDS',',')) AS (uid:chararray);

useridfilter = JOIN filteredInput BY useriD, flatteneduserids BY  uid USING 'replicated';
```

so Now I tried another way of declaring flatteneduserids which results in the error Undefined alias: IN

```
flatteneduserids = FOREACH IN GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT('$REQUIREDUSERIDS',',')) AS (uid:chararray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar use case. Tried the approach by declaring the constant value in %define and accessing the same inside IN clause, was not able to achieve the objective. (Refer : [Declare a comma seperated string constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779866/declare-a-comma-seperated-string-constant))

A thought worth contemplating ....

If the condition inside IN clause is a static/ reference/ meta kind of data, then would suggest to declare this in a static file. We can then read the data at run time and do an inner join with input data to retrieve the matching records.

```
input_data = LOAD '$INPUT' USING PigStorage('|') AS (user_id:chararray ...)
static_data = LOAD ... AS (req_user_id:chararray

required_data = JOIN input_data BY useriD, static_data BY req_user_id  USING 'replicated';

required_data_fmt = -- project required fields.
```

Comment: Thanks Murali..I tried the approach of declaring a variable and then using Flatten and stringSplit to join

Comment: I have edited the original post to show the new code and error.. I think there is an issue with the Flatten statement

Comment: @user2330278 : As I said earlier, I was not able to achieve the objective using %declare statement, we can NOT use FLATTEN or any function directly, we can use it while iterating over the records of an alias. i.e. while using FOREACH ...GENERATE statement.

Comment: Murali. I was able to run my job by having the fixed array in a file and then doing the load and join. But I did see statements like Foreach IN generate() in pig. So I will research that more. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to figure out how to do this in memory
So as per Murali's suggestion I added the user ids in a file..load the file and then do a join...that worked as expected for mr